# use a xslt variable from calling template inside called template

Tags: xslt

There are several xslt templates: calling_template_a, calling_template_b, and so on..., which I cannot edit, but all have access to a variable, let's call it var_a. In other words, calling_template_a could say, `<xsl:variable name="my_var" select="$var_a"/>`, as could calling_template_b, but var_a isn't necessarily the same value in templates A and B.

All the calling templates call the same template, let's call it shared_template, like this:

`<xsl:call-template name="shared_template">`

Is it possible to access the calling template's value of var_a from within shared_template **without** explicitly passing it with a with_param like this in each of the calling templates:

`<xsl:call-template name="shared_template">
     <xsl:with-param name="passed_var" select = "$var_a"/>
 </xsl:call-template>`

Could something in shared_template like:

`<xsl:param name="passed_var" select="../var_a"/>`

be used?

Comment: If using XSLT 2.0, try using tunnel parameters https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-xslt20-20031112/#tunnel-params

Comment: The answer to your question, as asked, is no. The variable declared in the calling template is limited in scope to its parent template and does not exist outside of that scope.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @dave. But from the documentation it looks like tunnel parameters are set in with-param statements that are part of the call-template statements that I can't change for each of the calling templates. If I could set var_a as a tunnel parameter from the java where it is given to the calling templates, that would work. Do you know if that is possible?

Comment: *If I could set var_a as a tunnel parameter from the java where it is given to the calling templates, that would work. Do you know if that is possible?* It's possible in Saxon 9.7 using `Xslt30Transformer.setInitialTemplateParameters(params, true)`. It may not be possible with other APIs.